# What/where is the origin of "every time I carry you this way"

Tags: puranas, translation-request, translation

I was recently reading Heinrich Zimmer's *Myths and Symbols in Indian Art and Civilization* and encountered his explanation of the cycles of Yuga's. He recounted from one of the Puranas the description of Vishnu in his boar incarnation turning to the goddess earth and remarking "Every time i carry you this way..." I was quite moved by this translation but I have not been able to find it's original form in the Puranas. Would anyone be able to point out where in the Puranas this comes from or provide the Sanskrit translation?

Comment: read the footnote to the quote in the book you cited. It has the source in the footnote.

Comment: There is no footnote or source in the book. I have also looked online, every place I have found where this quote is mentioned, there is no reference to the location in the Puranas or the translation in sanskrit